# ruby - Putting elements of an array of arrays in a variable by index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this array of arrays :

> array = [["z1", "y1", "x1"], ["z2", "y2", "x2"], ["z3", "y3", "x3"], ["z4", "y4" , "x4"]]

I want to be able to retrieve elements of the array within the bigger array by an index and putting them in a variable.
For example for the index *1* the output should be :

> output = [["y1"], ["y2"], ["y3"], ["y4"]]

I want also after that to be able to push these results to form a new array. In other words, I want to re-order the elements of the array (if you could find a better solution than retrieving and pushing).

Example :

> output_x = [["x1"], ["x2"], ["x3"], ["x4"]]
>
> output_y = [["y1"], ["y2"], ["y3"], ["y4"]]
>
> output_z = [["z1"], ["z2"], ["z3"], ["z4"]]

So the final result should look like :

> result = [["x1", "y1", "z1"], ["x2", "y2", "z2"], ["x3", "y3", "z3"], ["x4", "y4" , "z4"]]

I really want to find a solution for this.
Thank you

**PS : x,y and z are coordinates. Forget about `sort`ing them**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want `Array#transpose`, which is the inverse of `Array#zip`:

```
[["z1", "y1", "x1"],
 ["z2", "y2", "x2"],
 ["z3", "y3", "x3"],
 ["z4", "y4" , "x4"]].transpose

=> [["z1", "z2", "z3", "z4"],
    ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"],
    ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"]]
```

From there, it's easy enough to split those into individual arrays. If you just want to translate the arrays into XYZ (rather than ZYX), then you may perhaps want to just map the reversed arrays:

```
[["z1", "y1", "x1"],
 ["z2", "y2", "x2"],
 ["z3", "y3", "x3"],
 ["z4", "y4" , "x4"]].map(&:reverse)
=> [["x1", "y1", "z1"],
    ["x2", "y2", "z2"],
    ["x3", "y3", "z3"],
    ["x4", "y4", "z4"]]
```

You could also just map an arbitrary order. For example, to map from your ZYX to XZY, you would use:

```
coordinates.map {|c| [c[2], c[0], c[1]] }
```

Comment: It's not always from ZYX to XYZ.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a better example, then. `transpose` will allow you to get what you need, though, since you can just index the individual arrays from the transposed array to get all the values for a given subindex from the original array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a sort on each element in `array` like this

```
array.each do |e|
  e.sort!
end
```

if you run the code above, your `array` would look like what you want for

```
result = [["x1", "y1", "z1"], ["x2", "y2", "z2"], ["x3", "y3", "z3"], ["x4", "y4" , "z4"]]
```

For more information about sort, check [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#sort-21-method)

**Update**

According to your comment below, you have coordinates in each sub array. Since the order right now is `z, y, x`, and you want them in `x, y, z`. Reversing the elements in the array would do the trick.

```
array.each do |e|
  e.reverse!
end
```

For more information about reverse, check [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse)

Comment: X,Y and Z are coordinates. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information, I was under the assumption that you just wanna sort the string like you stated in the question

Comment: And if there is something else that z, y, x and I want them in x, y, z

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the final outcome:

```
array  = [["z1", "y1", "x1"], ["z2", "y2", "x2"], ["z3", "y3", "x3"], ["z4", "y4" , "x4"]]
option = []

array.each do |item|
  option << item.reverse
end

puts option.inspect
```